# What are independent columns and rows?

Tags: linear-algebra

One questions asks if A is not a square matrix and rank A=2, does it have independent columns or rows? What does independent columns and rows mean here?

Comment: Linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^m$ for rows and $\Bbb R^n$ for columns if the matrix is $m\times n$.

Comment: The vectors $(1,2)$ and $(3,2)$ are [linearly independent](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~eitan/la5.pdf), so the matrix $\pmatrix{1 & 3 \\ 2 & 2}$ has linearly independent columns.

Answer (score 1):

Since the rank of a matrix is defined as the dimension of vector space spanned by its columns, $rank(A)=2$ tells us that 2 columns of $A$ are linearly independent. In this context, the question is asking if whether the columns (or rows) of $A$ have a linearly independent subset. For instance if $A$ is a $2\times 3$ matrix and $rank(A)=2$, then we know that two column vectors are linearly independent. i.e. if $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23}
\end{pmatrix}$, then two of the column vectors (let's just say the first two) are linearly independent i.e. $c_1\begin{pmatrix} 
x_{11} \\
x_{21} 
\end{pmatrix}+ c_2\begin{pmatrix} 
x_{12}\\
x_{22} 
\end{pmatrix}=0$ is only satisfied when $c_1=c_2=0$.